# Mobaxterm console and logging

Tags: logging, console, mobaxterm

got some problem
i need to start console with command line now it looks like:

```
MobaXterm.exe -newtab "waitforX; telnet [Device.FirstAddress]"
```

1st problem is logging, without "`waitforX`" i got wrong tab name(i need ip)

2nd problem is log naming

> [shell localhost]  (2022-05-27_120323).log

it come from 1st problem

putty+conemu works well for this job, putty logging at least got `append` option(nwm it will solve problem for me, if i'll got 1 appendable file)
here we got MuTTy, and it is not configurable

need any idea, how i can solve this